# C++ memory preallocation for vector via constructor fails

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I use VS2013 (Win7 64). I discovered some strange behavior. When I reserve memory using the reserve method, the code works, but when I reserve via constructor, it throws bad_alloc

```
const int elemNumber = 100000000;
try
{
    //std::vector<int>* intVector = new std::vector<int>(elemNumber); // throws bad_alloc
    std::vector<int>* intVector = new std::vector<int>();
    intVector->reserve(elemNumber); //OK

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < elemNumber; ++i)
    {
        intVector->push_back(i);
    }

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "Time interval: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << endl;
    delete intVector;
    cout << "Done" << endl;
}
catch (bad_alloc exc)
{
    cout << exc.what() << endl;
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Both cases work for me, VS2013 (x64).

Comment: The constructor doesn't `reserve`, it `resize`s. Is it possible you just run out of memory?

Comment: @hlt `reserve` would also "run out of memory".

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but why are you dynamically allocating the vector? That gives you a needless memory leak.

Comment: @juanchopanza it is just for example. Any way allocating it statically gives the same exception

Comment: I get the same error in msvc++ 2012 but not with gcc. On the other hand, it takes gcc 1.2 seconds do run your working example while msvc takes 33 seconds.

Comment: @CamelToe Make sure that you didn't forget to switch to release mode? For me it takes 0.94sec

Comment: did you test it one after another in the same run? so the first one using `reserve()` consumed all available memory? if not better post 2 minimal complete examples to support your claim, your code does lots of unrelated things

Comment: One big difference is that your constructor-sized vector has twice as many elements after the `push_back` loop, and is going to need even more than that while resizing. Are you sure that `new` is throwing and not `push_back`?

Comment: @moldbnilo thank you! My bad, I should have checked size in both cases. Silly mistake

Comment: Please be clearer in future about which line throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    const int elemNumber = 5;
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> intVector(elemNumber); // throws bad_alloc

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (int i = 0; i < elemNumber; ++i)
        {
            //intVector[i] = i;
            intVector.push_back(i);
        }

        //prints the vector
        for (auto& i : intVector)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }

        end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        std::cout << "Time interval: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc exc)
    {
        std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
    }


    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The constructor first resizes the vector to have 5 elements. After that it pushes 5 more elements to the vector making it double the size and the first 5 elements are initialized to 0.

If you were to use the reserve function instead the size of the vector would only be 5*sizeof(int) with preallocated memory.

Using:

```
vectorInt[i] = i;
```

instead together with the resize constructor will result in the vector being the same size as if you were to use reserve and will not throw std::bad_alloc.

The reason for std::bad_alloc is most likely that you run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

hlt has already answered this in a comment...

> The constructor doesn't `reserve`, it `resize`s. Is it possible you just run out of memory?

...so posting an explanation as community wiki...

This...

```
std::vector<int>* intVector = new std::vector<int>(elemNumber); // throws bad_alloc
```

...needs to populate the vector with default-constructed elements, so it's writing to all the pages of memory needed for `elemNumber` `int`s, and the initial `size()` is `elemNumber`, while...

```
std::vector<int>* intVector = new std::vector<int>();
intVector->reserve(elemNumber); //OK
```

...is just reserving virtual addresses for the memory - the OS doesn't need to find actual backing memory until elements are added later; the initial `size()` is still `0`.

The program then goes to `push_back` lots of elements - for the first case, they're *in addition* to those default-constructed elements already in the `vector`, which is why it's running out of memory.

Remember too that the memory momentarily used during resizing (caused by `push_back` beyond `capacity`) increases as the container gets bigger, as does the amount by which the container tends to pad out the capacity so it won't have to resize again too soon, and whatever memory's needed must be contiguous in virtual address space (which is primarily a potential issue here for a 32-bit app).

Comment: This is a good explanation, but it would be even better if it weren't assuming that every OS out there did page-based virtual memory... some don't.

Comment: @DevSolar: the first sentence in the question is *"I use VS2013 (Win7 64)."*... I don't see a reason *not* to explain the implications....

Answer (score 1):

I get a `bad_alloc` exception on MSVS2015 RC, too. The `bad_alloc` does not occur in the construction line, however.

First this line:

```
std::vector<int>* intVector = new std::vector<int>(elemNumber);
```

allocates storage for 100000000 integers an then the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elemNumber; ++i)
{
    intVector->push_back(i);
}
```

adds another 100000000 integers where at some point on the way to 200000000 (150000000 in my case) `bad_alloc` is thrown.

Actually, MSVC calls `_Reallocate` for `225000000` values since there is a function `_Grow_to` which tries to grow by `50%` if possible according to `max_size()`.